# The changes between older and newer versions of Vuforia Engine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, android-augmented-reality

I have followed the tutorial by this guy https://youtu.be/BRScnNUg730 but I have so many red lines in my code. I think it is because the version of his Vuforia was older than mine. And as I know there are some changes between older and newer versions of Vuforia. Can you tell me what I should change in my code?[screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5Siv.png)

I tried to google how to fix this problem, but it didn't help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not share your code as image. Please use the built-in formatting tools of StackOverflow.